# Can not connect to Local Web UI of Kura

Tags: eclipse, iot, kura

I want to install Kura in my computer (ubuntun 14.04, JDK1.7) with eclipse. I followed http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/configurable_component.html. My problem is I can not connect to localhost:8080.

In console of eclipse, I inputted 'ss' and its outputs are

```
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521
1   RESOLVED    slf4j.log4j12_1.6.0
                Master=39
2   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
3   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522
4   ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
5   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841
6   ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.2.v20111214-1400
7   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent_1.0.1
8   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522
9   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin_0.9.5
10  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi_1.0.0.qualifier
11  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.core_1.0.1
12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.io_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
13  ACTIVE      log4j_1.2.17
                Fragments=24
14  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.metatype_1.2.0.v20120522-1841
15  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822
16  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.io_2.4.0
17  ACTIVE      com.gwt.user_0.2.0
18  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.net_3.1.0.v201205071737
19  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.core.net_1.0.1
20  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.dependencymanager_3.0.0
21  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration_1.0.1
22  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841
23  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm_1.2.1
24  RESOLVED    log4j.apache-log4j-extras_1.1.0
                Master=13
25  ACTIVE      org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.0
26  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841
27  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
28  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049
29  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522
30  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522
31  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud_1.0.1
32  ACTIVE      org.json_1.0.0.v201011060100
33  ACTIVE      javax.usb.api_1.0.2
34  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.emulator_1.0.1
35  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20120522-1822
36  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515
37  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.api_1.0.1
38  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522
39  ACTIVE      slf4j.api_1.6.4
                Fragments=1
40  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.configurable_1.0.0.qualifier
41  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522
42  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.cm_1.0.400.v20120522-1841
43  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705
44  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522
45  INSTALLED   org.eclipse.kura.web_1.0.1
46  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto_1.0.1
47  ACTIVE      osgi.cmpn_4.3.0.201111022214
48  ACTIVE      javax.usb.common_1.0.2
```

comment 'ls' gave

```
All Components:
ID  State           Component Name          Located in bundle
1   Active      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent           org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent(bid=7)
2   Active      org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi         org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi(bid=10)
3   Active      org.eclipse.equinox.event           org.eclipse.equinox.event(bid=28)
4   Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.example.configurable           org.eclipse.kura.example.configurable(bid=40)
5   Active      org.eclipse.kura.crypto.CryptoService           org.eclipse.kur
```

Is there anybody ever had this problem may help me, please. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... The answer was I downloaded the wrong package.
There are 2 Developers Workspaces for download. On the left side without the WebUI.
Try to download the Developers Workspace on the right side (Extended Downloads) [Developers Workspace (With Web UI)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/kura_downloads/user_workspace/release/1.1.2/user_workspace_archive_1.1.2.zip) https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have lots of `INSTALLED` or `RESOLVED` bundles, which should be `ACTIVE` after Kura started. This might be the reason of fail activation of **Kura Web UI** service. Because the web service might depends on other bundles or services.

So if you still haven't solve it yet, try followings:

1. Change log level by editing `/opt/eclipse/kura/kura/log4j.properties` file. Set `log4j.rootLogger=INFO,kura` to `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,kura`. And restart kura.
2. See `/var/log/kura.log`, there may be some debug messages.
3. See `/var/log/kura-console.log`, there may be some exceptions that explained why the bundle is not activated.

If you still don't know why, post it here and we can discuss it.

Hope this solve your problem, cheers